# Run riverpod FutureProvider `AsyncValue.when` in a VoidCallback or Function

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I am trying to change a value based on the FutureProvider, which is triggered when the user presses a button.

The `onTap` callback:

```dart
ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              final promptResp = ref.watch(
                getProvider(
                  Tuple2(
                    '/gen-image',
                    {'prompt': controller.text},
                  ),
                ),
              );

              promptResp.when<void>(data: (value) {
                ref.read(isLoading.notifier).state = false;
                final data = jsonDecode(value.body);
                ref.read(imagesProvider.notifier).state = data;
              }, error: (e, r) {
                return;
              }, loading: () {
                ref.read(isLoading.notifier).state = true;
              });
            },
```

and the Provider:

```dart
final getProvider = FutureProvider.family(
    (ref, Tuple2<String?, Map<String, dynamic>?> info) async {
  final path = info.item1;
  final params = info.item2;

  final url = backendUrl().replace(queryParameters: params, path: path);

  final resp = await http.get(url, headers: {
    'X-FIREBASE_TOKEN': await ref.read(authProvider).currentUser!.getIdToken()
  });

  return resp;
});
```

So on the button press, the `loading` callback is called, but when the data is receive, the `data` callback is not triggered. It seems on rebuild, the execution of `onTap` ceases.

How can I trigger this callback via a button?

I have used `AsyncValue.whenData` as well, but the callback is still not triggered as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use `ref.read` in callback:

```dart
final promptResp = ref.read(
                getProvider(
                  Tuple2(
                    '/gen-image',
                    {'prompt': controller.text},
                  ),
                ),
              );
```

Don't use `ref.watch` in callback and `init` method for widget.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out after posting it. Thank you for the response.